# How to get value of jsonObject inside a jsonObject swift 4?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I use FCM to send push notification to my iOS app.When user click on the notification tray,the data handle by the function below:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        print(userInfo['data'])
}
```

The `userInfo` is a `[AnyHashable:Any]` type.I successfully get the data from the `userInfo['data']`.So here is the data structure for `userInfo['data']` :

```
'{"data":
   {
    "title":"My app",
    "message":"The message here",
    "payload":{
        "post_id":"602"
        },
    "timestamp":"2018-03-10 14:12:08"
    }
 }'
```

Here is how I tried :

```
 if let dataString = userInfo["data"] as? String {

        let data = dataString.data(using: .utf8)!

        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [String : Any]
            {
                let message = json["message"] as? String ?? "No message here"
                let title = json["title"] as String ?? ""

                //here is the problem..I have no idea to do it here
                let payload = json["payload"] as? [String : Int] ?? [:]

                for element in payload {
                    if let postId = element["post_id"] {
                        //print("postId = \(postId)")
                    }


                }
            } else {
                print("bad json")
            }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
```

So as shown in above,I have no problem to get value of `title`,`message` and `timestamp` inside the `data` json.

But I have to idea how to get the value of `post_id` which is inside `payload` array.

So in this case,how to get the value of `post_id` from the `data` json above? Thanks.

Comment: Every JSON value in double quotes is a `String`. Even `"602"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access post id like this

```
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        if let data = userInfo["data"] as? [String: Any],
            let payload = data["payload"] as? [String: Any],
            let postId = payload["post_id"] as? String{
            print("post id \(postId)")
        }else{
            print("there is no post id inside the payload")
        }
    }
```

Comment: hey bro,still cant..I tried..why I cant get the payload ya??

Comment: the data here 100% have post_id inside it

Comment: I have given my answer as per the payload sample you have posted in your question, so are you sure you are having payload same as above?

Comment: I check back,it seems like dont have the "data" word..can u show me if dont have the "data" word? please...

Comment: I check the logic it seem the problem happen in ` if let data = userInfo["data"] as? [String: Any]` here...

Comment: can you please share the exact payload data which you have?